# Compute Engine VM instances network errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am using compute engine VM instances to migrate data through G Suite Migration for Microsoft Outlook(GSMMO)
but the problem that when I leave the machine running and after couple of hours when I see it again an error said "Migration failed due to network error".

[image: Migration Network error]

Also I am exporting PST file from Outlook in another instance and the same problem occurs and the exporting stopped and the error said "Network problems are preventing connection to Microsoft Exchange".

[image: exporting error]

I want to know why this happens and how to prevent this? I am unable to complete anything because it stops every couple of hours and I had to start it again!!

Comment: You should contact GCP Support https://cloud.google.com/support/ in this case. They're able to help you and solve your issue.

Comment: I think you should contact support [GSuite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) instead.

Comment: What size GCP VM instance? Does Stackdriver show any errors for this instance? Are there any errors in Windows Event Log? I have rarely seen networking fail in GCP. I have seen issues due to out of memory, excessive CPU, etc for too small instances. Edit your question with more details. You will need them here or for G Suite / GCP Support.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I only have the basic support for billing :S So I asked here If anyone have this problem before and could help

Comment: @Jescanellas I contacted them but they haven't responded yet but I don't think it is a GSMMO's problem as there is also network error when exporting PST file from Outlook

Comment: @JohnHanley
The Size of VM instance is 60 GB and machine type n1-standard-2 (2 vCPUs, 7.5 GB memory) but I have many instances one its size is 200 GB and all have the network error. Stack driver shows no error and windows events log shows the error said network error with number like xx000001

Comment: Make sure that you do not have a corrupted PST. Use the tool `scanpst.exe`